# how to plot a graph on lattice with two different colors

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to plot the following data

```
> data
  epochs      rmse learner momentum
1      1 0.2992122     0.3      0.0
2      1 0.3082895     0.1      0.2
3      1 0.2955586     0.5      0.2
4      1 0.2955182     0.3      0.4
5     11 0.2916979     0.3      0.0
6     11 0.2919140     0.1      0.2
7     11 0.2928490     0.5      0.2
8     11 0.2906339     0.3      0.4
```

I want a graph that has `epochs` on x-axis, `rmse` on y-axist, and graphs a separate line for each row while labeling the `learner` and `momentum`.

I tried plot it like this:

```
 > xyplot(rmse ~ epochs, data=data, groups = data$learner,
       type = "l",
       auto.key =
           list(space = "right", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE))
```

but this is creating graph with only `learner` values, it is not taking into account the momentum as well.

[image]

How can I fix the graph such that the labels read:

```
L = 0.1, M=0.2 <somecolor>
L = 0.3, M=0.0 <somecolor>
L = 0.5, M=0.2 <somecolor>
L = 0.3, M=0.4 <somecolor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the groups to be the interaction of `learner` and `momentum`:

```
xyplot(rmse ~ epochs, data=data,
       groups = interaction(learner,momentum, sep=" : ", drop=TRUE),
       type = "l",
       auto.key =
           list(space = "right", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE))
```

[image]

(Note that we don't need to specify `data$learner`, etc, as the data frame is pulled into the environment.)

Above, `interaction` is creating a factor based on the inputs `learner` and `momentum` (after coercing these to factors), but we can create any factor that we desire to use for the groups.  In particular, we can use `paste` to create a vector to use for the groups, with the labels that you want:

```
xyplot(rmse ~ epochs, data=data,
       groups = paste("L =", learner, "M =", momentum),
       type = "l",
       auto.key =
           list(space = "right", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: ah, precisely what I wanted. I just didn't know how to get both of them. Thanks!!